# How to make a listBox trigger a handler when there is only one item?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is a script that demonstrate the issue I have ([test online here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzzaWHQFMCMvyeAm93pNrogOhjksaKvzF32hIbFTbzCX1bYPJAx/exec))

```js
var lbArray1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];

function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','20px')
  app.add(vPanel);
  var lb1 = app.createListBox().setName('lb1').setId('lb1').setVisibleItemCount(1);
  var lb2 = app.createListBox().setName('lb2').setId('lb2').setVisibleItemCount(4);
  var lb3 = app.createListBox().setName('lb3').setId('lb3').setVisibleItemCount(1);
  lb3.addItem(lbArray1[0]);
    for(var i in lbArray1){
      lb1.addItem(lbArray1[i]);
      lb2.addItem(lbArray1[i]);
      }
  var msg = app.createLabel('waiting for trigger').setId('msg');
  vPanel.add(lb1).add(lb2).add(lb3).add(msg);
  var Handler = app.createServerHandler('test').addCallbackElement(vPanel);
  lb1.addChangeHandler(Handler);
  lb2.addClickHandler(Handler);
  lb3.addClickHandler(Handler);// I tried different trigger modes without success
  return app;
}

function test(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var msg = app.getElementById('msg');
  msg.setText('triggered by '+e.parameter.source)
  return app;
}
```

ListBox 3 has only one item and shows only one item *(I have this situation in an app that uses a popup to show folders content while adapting the list size to its content, sometimes I can have just 1 file in a folder)*

ListBox 3 never triggers the handler unless I change the `setVisibleItemCount` to 2 or more...

the code I use to adapt the list size goes simply like that :

```js
...
ODlist.setVisibleItemCount(numItem > 6 ? 6 : numItem > 1 ? numItem : 2)
...
```

and I really would prefer to set the last number to 1, it would be looking so nice ;-) but I can't .

Any workaround idea ?

---

EDIT : for now I found that using   `lb3.addMouseOverHandler(Handler);` is a useable solution but this handler causes some issues when more than one item is visible... I'd rather find something more elegant.

Comment: when I deployed your code, lb3 handler does in fact fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand if this isn't want you want, but it was my solution to the problem.  I just simply added a list item that was a user prompt like: "Select a Spreadsheet".  From my code:

```
var files = DocsList.getFolder("Incoming Product Data").getFiles();
fileChooser.addItem("Select a Spreadsheet"); 
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileChooser.addItem(files[i].getId());
```

The only other thing I had to do was then build an if statement into the trigger, so that if someone select a file, but then switches back to the prompt "Select a Spreadsheet" that it doesn't throw an error by attempting to handle the prompt as an actual fileId.

Best I could do.

Comment: not bad at all :) I'll keep that as first backup solution along with my mouseOver trick until someone (ever) suggests something else (who knows?). thanks anyway.